# Find semicolon in dataframe R

Tags: r, regex, dataframe

I have this dataframe:

```
id <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
org <- c(NA, "Org-A", "Org-A;Org-B", "Org-C", "Org-A;Org-B;Org-C")
df <- data.frame(id, org)
```

I want to find the number of organizations for each ID. But the 'Organization' in this table is separated by a semicolon, the result I want to achieve:

```
  id               org   num
1  1              <NA>   NA
2  2             Org-A   1
3  3       Org-A;Org-B   2
4  4             Org-C   1
5  5 Org-A;Org-B;Org-C   3
```

I think to solve this problem require something like this:

```
df['num'] = ifelse(is.na(df['org']), NA, ifelse( "something about regex", "count the number of semicolons", 1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `str_count` on the delimiter `;` and then add 1

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
         mutate(num = str_count(org, ";")+1)
```

-output

```
df
#  id               org num
#1  1              <NA>  NA
#2  2             Org-A   1
#3  3       Org-A;Org-B   2
#4  4             Org-C   1
#5  5 Org-A;Org-B;Org-C   3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some other options with base R:

- `gregexpr`

```
transform(
  df,
  num = replace(lengths(gregexpr("Org-", org)), is.na(org), NA)
)
```

- `strsplit`

```
transform(
  df,
  num = replace(lengths(strsplit(org, ";")),is.na(org),NA)
)
```